# Spring-Batch @StepScope and @JobScope do not work on a Step used in a Job with transitions

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I use Spring with Spring-Batch vesrion 4.0.1 and Spring-Boot verion 2.0.6

I have some problemes when I use @JobScope or @StepScope annotations on Step bean when it's used in a job build with transitions.

I will illustrate my problem in a simple example :

```java
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class ExampleJobConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleJobConfig.class);
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job simpleExampleJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("simpleExampleJob")
                .start(simpleExampleStep(null)).on("COMPLETED").end()
                .from(simpleExampleStep(null)).on("*").fail()
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step simpleExampleStep(@Value("#{jobParameters['myParam']}") String myParam) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("simpleExampleStep")
                .tasklet(simpleExampleTasklet(myParam))
                .build();
    }

    public Tasklet simpleExampleTasklet(String param) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            LOG.debug(param);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
}
```

This code throw a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.simpleExampleStep': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
...
```

But with this job declaration, this code works fine :

```java
    @Bean
    public Job simpleExampleJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("simpleExampleJob")
                .start(simpleExampleStep(null))
                .build();
    }
```

I don't uderstand why it doesn't work with the transitions because this works with the same code but without the transitions.

Can you help me to understand please :) ?

Comment: There is an open issue for this here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2747

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Is this above issues resolved now ?